# Blazor Wasm - JS : One button to download multiple files

Tags: download, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to make a button to download multiple images in a Blazor webassembly .NET 6 app.

So I've made a button :

```
<button class="btn icon-download" @onclick=DownloadImages></button>
```

And my method :

```
private async Task DownloadImages()
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var p in Pictures)
    {
        // TODO : needs to take the same extension
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromUrl", p.Url, $"picture-{i++:00}.jpeg");
    }
}
```

Which call the following javascript function :

```
function downloadFromUrl(url, filename) {
    
    // Create the <a> element and click on it
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.target = "_self";

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);

    console.log(url, ' downloaded to ', filename);
}
```

I have 2 issues :

- First, when I click on the button, all the downloads are cancelled, except the last one
  => Do I need to wait the download finished ? How could I do that in Javascript ?
- Second, once downloaded, the image name doesn't change and keeps the name from the URL. How can I rename it when saving in Download user folder ?

Comment: the requests will interrupt each other and cancel out till the last one remains.  I think the solution would be to use as many iframes as there are files.  Each src would be set to a URL which returns a file.  So the click would generate each iframe with src including each file's ID (ex: my_site.com/download?fileid=thisFileID )

Comment: Be sure to return a File  (function return type Task<IActionResult>)...  This will also allow for concurrent/async downloads.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll check that and come back with a working solution if it works